# How to synchronize scrolling positions for several iframes

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an HTML layout based on tabs (say 5).
In each tab I load an iframe. The iframe contents are variations of one another that the user can compare by switching tabs.

How can I, in javascript, synchronize the scrolling of all iframes vertically and horizontally?
In other words, scrolling in one iframe should scroll by the same amount all other iframes, allowing the user to compare the same data.

Bonus points: iframe content is loaded only when the user opens the tab for the first time. So newly opened iframes should directly scroll to the same place as already opened iframes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

While this works for divs, it does not work for iframes.

Here's what you can do,

```
$($('#iframe1').contents()).scroll(function(){
    $($('#iframe2').contents()).scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
});
```

With [jQuery's scroll event](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/scroll), you should be able to synchronize them.

**Edit**: No plugins required.  Here's the code that worked for me:

```
<html>
<head>
<SCRIPT language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT>
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#div1").scroll(function () { 
        $("#div2").scrollTop($("#div1").scrollTop());
        $("#div2").scrollLeft($("#div1").scrollLeft());
    });
$("#div2").scroll(function () { 
        $("#div1").scrollTop($("#div2").scrollTop());
        $("#div1").scrollLeft($("#div2").scrollLeft());
    });

});

</SCRIPT>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1" style="overflow:auto;height:100px;width:200px;border:1px solid black;">
Test..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................test
<BR/><BR/>
Test..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................test
<BR/><BR/>
Test..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................test
<BR/><BR/>
Test..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................test
<BR/><BR/>
Test..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................test
<BR/><BR/>
Test..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................test
<BR/><BR/>
Test..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................test
<BR/><BR/>
Test..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................test
<BR/><BR/>
Test..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................test
<BR/><BR/>
Test..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................test
<BR/><BR/>
Test..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................test
<BR/><BR/>
Test..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................test
<BR/><BR/>
Test..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................test
<BR/><BR/>
Test..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................test
<BR/><BR/>
Test..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................test
<BR/><BR/>
</div>

<div id="div2" style="overflow:auto;height:100px;width:200px;border:1px solid black;">
Test..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................test
<BR/><BR/>
Test..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................test
<BR/><BR/>
Test..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................test
<BR/><BR/>
Test..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................test
<BR/><BR/>
Test..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................test
<BR/><BR/>
Test..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................test
<BR/><BR/>
Test..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................test
<BR/><BR/>
Test..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................test
<BR/><BR/>
Test..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................test
<BR/><BR/>
Test..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................test
<BR/><BR/>
Test..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................test
<BR/><BR/>
Test..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................test
<BR/><BR/>
Test..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................test
<BR/><BR/>
Test..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................test
<BR/><BR/>
Test..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................test
<BR/><BR/>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for this. You helped me answer a question I asked that nobody there could answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256086/how-can-i-make-2-divs-scroll-at-the-same-time/

Answer (score 7):

I synchronize overflowed div's using code like this:

```
frame1.onscroll = function(e) {
   frame2.scrollTop = frame1.scrollTop;
   frame2.scrollLeft = frame1.scrollLeft;
 };
```

Answer (score 2):

Accepted solution works only if divs have the same width.
If not, it causes an infinite loop: #div1 scrolls #div2, then #div2's scroll event scrolls #div1 etc :)

Edited solution:

```
var skip = false;
$("#div1").scroll(function () {
    if (skip){skip=false; return;} else skip=true; 
    $("#div2").scrollTop($("#div1").scrollTop());
    $("#div2").scrollLeft($("#div1").scrollLeft());
});
$("#div2").scroll(function () { 
    $("#div1").scrollTop($("#div2").scrollTop());
    $("#div1").scrollLeft($("#div2").scrollLeft());
});
```

Comment: Does that solve the infinite loop problem? ISTM "skip" flips between true and false infinitely.

Comment: It solves infinite loop problem: every second call will be skipped. ("skip" variable flips, but when $("#div2").scroll(...) calls it: it will be skipped.)

Comment: +1 for first comment that talks about infinite loop issues when updating scrolltop. I found Chrome and Firefox work without the skip but IE8 needs it or it locks up.

Comment: You will probably need a setTimeout() to delay flipping "skip"

Answer (score 2):

I think this answer can fix the infinite loop.

```
      var jsScroll0;
      var jsScroll1;
      windows[0].on('scroll.scrollInTheSameTime', function() {
        if (jsScroll1 === true) {
          jsScroll1 = false;
          return;
        }
        jsScroll0 = true;
        windows[1].scrollTop(windows[0].scrollTop());
        windows[1].scrollLeft(windows[0].scrollLeft());
      });
      windows[1].on('scroll.scrollInTheSameTime', function() {
        if (jsScroll0 === true) {
          jsScroll0 = false;
          return;
        }
        jsScroll1 = true;
        windows[0].scrollTop(windows[1].scrollTop());
        windows[0].scrollLeft(windows[1].scrollLeft());
        // jsScroll = false;
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the mentioned solutions didn't work for me.
The following javascript solution synchronizes the scrollbar of two iframes:

```
    var sourceFrame = document.getElementById('sourceFrame');
    var resultFrame = document.getElementById('resultFrame');
    sourceFrame.onload = function () {
    resultFrame.onload = function () {
        sourceFrame.contentWindow.onscroll = function(e) {
            var sourceScrollY = sourceFrame.contentWindow.scrollY;
            var sourceScrollX = sourceFrame.contentWindow.scrollX;
            resultFrame.contentWindow.scrollTo(sourceScrollX, sourceScrollY)
        };
        resultFrame.contentWindow.onscroll = function(e) {
            var resultScrollY = resultFrame.contentWindow.scrollY;
            var resultScrollX = resultFrame.contentWindow.scrollX;
            sourceFrame.contentWindow.scrollTo(resultScrollX, resultScrollY)
        };
    }
}
```

PS: I am not sure if you need to wait for the second frame to load, but for me it was a robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

To synchronise an arbitrary number of elements use the following code:

```
jQuery.fn.synchroniseScroll = function() {

        var elements = this;
        if (elements.length <= 1) return;

        elements.scroll(
        function() {
            var left = $(this).scrollLeft();
            var top = $(this).scrollTop();
            elements.each(
            function() {
                if ($(this).scrollLeft() != left) $(this).scrollLeft(left);
                if ($(this).scrollTop() != top) $(this).scrollTop(top);
            }
            );
        });
    }
```

Using this is SUPER simple.  Lets say you have several divs defined as:

```
<div class=”scrollDiv” style=”overflow:auto;”> .. some large content</div>
```

To synchronize the scrollbars’ on all divs with the class scrollDiv all you need to write is:

```
$(“.scrollDiv”).synchroniseScroll();
```

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matt/archive/2009/03/19/synchronizing-scrollbars-using-jquery.aspx