# Is there a jquery scrollbar plugin that can sync several instances?

Tags: jquery-plugins, scrollbar

The value of the scrollbar should be `0~100%`.

And the value of all scrollbar instances should always be the same.

Is there such a plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Scrollsync) seems to do what you want, though I don't know if it's compatible with the latest version of jQuery.

See also:

- [How to synchronize scrolling positions for several iframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762274/how-to-synchronize-scrolling-positions-for-several-iframes)
- [Synchronizing Scrollbars using JQuery](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matt/archive/2009/03/19/synchronizing-scrollbars-using-jquery.aspx)