# jquery scrolling divs with mouse wheel

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm using the example provided in:
http://jsfiddle.net/9R4hZ/40/

to have divs scrolling with mouse wheel.
It works fine, but I would like to move 2 divs at the same time, instead of moving them one by one.

Is it feasible?

Comment: No offense, but that's an absolutely horrid user experience.

Comment: @AlienWebguy No offense, but diff tools do it all the time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389228/scroll-2-scrollbars-with-jquery-the-same-time and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256086/how-can-i-make-2-divs-scroll-at-the-same-time

Comment: I'm talking about the scrolling experience itself - not scrolling two divs with a single mousewheel event.

Answer (score 0):

To update the scroll position of div A when div B gets scrolled, listen for the onscroll event and update the scroll position of the other div.

```
$('#a').scroll(function(){
    $('#b').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
});
```