# C#, how to scroll two iframe (in a Table) simultaneously

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, iframe

i want to scroll 2 iframes simultaneously in the web page. Is there a way to do that? I have tried a lot but didn't find any solution.

```js
$('#one').contentwindow.scrollTop = $('two').contentwindow.scrollTop;
$('#two').contentwindow.scrollTop = $('one').contentwindow.scrollTop;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <iframe id="one" src="http://api.jquery.com/scroll/" style="width: 300px; height: 400px;"></iframe>
    </td>
    <td>
      <iframe id="two" src="http://api.jquery.com/scroll/" style="width: 300px; height: 400px;"></iframe>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note: My question here is how to synchronize scrolling with 2 iframe within the Table not DIV

Comment: Ur code just sets the scrollTops once when page is loaded... you should update the scrollTops everytime scroll event occurs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I synchronize the scroll position of two divs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236314/how-do-i-synchronize-the-scroll-position-of-two-divs)

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762274/how-to-synchronize-scrolling-positions-for-several-iframes

Comment: @AhsN Thanks for your help. can you please update the code snippet?