# How can I access JS variable name for rhandsontable rendered in Shiny?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, handsontable, rhandsontable

I use rhandsontable package to create interactive tables in Shiny app.

I need some cells to be selected **programmatically**, based on some other user actions.
However, I could not find such functionality in rhandsontable wrapper in R.

Meanwhile, it is definitely possible in native Handsontable.js with `selectCell()` 
function. I attach small jsfiddle example:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var data = [
    ["", "Ford", "Volvo", "Toyota", "Honda"],
    ["2014", 10, 11, 12, 13],
    ["2015", 20, 11, 14, 13],
    ["2016", 30, 15, 12, 13]
  ];

  var container = document.getElementById('example1');
  var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: data,
    minSpareRows: 1,
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: true,
    contextMenu: true
  });

  hot.selectCell(1, 0);
})
```

```css
</style><!--  --><script src="https://docs.handsontable.com/0.15.0/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://docs.handsontable.com/0.15.0/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://docs.handsontable.com/0.15.0/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.min.css">
```

```html
<div id="example1" class="hot handsontable"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vz74zeqo/

So, I could run `shinyjs::runjs('hot.selectCell(1,0);')` and everything would be fine.

But the question is: how can I learn the JS variable name, associated with the table, when it is created with `renderRHandsontable()` function in Shiny? (in my example it is named `hot`)

Thanks!

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post helped: 
[Search from a textInput to a Handsontable in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46289252/search-from-a-textinput-to-a-handsontable-in-shiny)

When I rendered rhandsontable via `output$myTab = renderRHandsontable({rhandsontabe(faithful)})` then I can use following command in JS `getInstance()`:

`HTMLWidgets.getInstance(myTab).hot.selectCell(0,1)`